# Reusable const for Jest tests

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to declare a `const` to be re-used for a number of tests.

For example:

```
describe('Component.vue', () => {

    const householdData = [ "here", "is", "some", "data" ]


    it('does stuff', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(HouseholdsComponent, {
            propsData: {
                original_household: householdData,
            }
        });

        expect(original_household).toContain("here");
    })

    it('does stuff', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(HouseholdsComponent, {
            propsData: {
                original_household: householdData,
            }
        });

        expect(original_household).toContain("is");
    })
});
```

The problem is that `householdData` does not seem to be getting set.

When I console.log `householdData`, I get this:

`{ clients: [Getter/Setter], networth: [Getter/Setter] }`

I've tried setting the data within the component like this as well:

`wrapper.vm.someVariable = householdData`

and that also gives me this:

`{ clients: [Getter/Setter], networth: [Getter/Setter] }`

However, it does work when I do this.

`wrapper.vm.someVariable = [ "here", "is", "some", "data" ]`

I would hate to have to keep setting this data in each test.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see a console log, and it looks like you're expecting `original_household` to contain something, but that variable isn't defined.  Blindly, I would say, maybe you need to copy the array, with `arr2 = [...arr]` or `arr2 = arr.slice()`

Comment: The `console.log` isn't in there, the code above is slimmed down version, but representative of the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. As opposed to setting the data as a const, I had to return it from a function.

```
function householdData() {
    return [ "here", "is", "some", "data" ]
}
```

Then I pass it to component props like this:

```
    const wrapper = mount(HouseholdsComponent, {
        propsData: {
            original_household: householdData(),
        }
    });
```

Voila!

Comment: this is why I said you need to copy the array: `data = [...householdData]` or `data = householdData.slice()` would have worked